# Phonegap zip plugin remove my files

Tags: javascript, cordova

When i use Phonegap zip plugin on https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/cordova-zip-plugin my file disappears.

```
fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/uploads.zip',
     function(entry) {
      zip.unzip(entry.toURL(), 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/uploads', function(data){
        if(data !== 0){
            alert('KO');
        }else{

            alert('Success');

        }
     }, progressCallback);              
   }, ...
```

When i upload my file without unziping it appear correctly in this folder file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0F1E3117-9961-4ACA-A895-530B6FF65C5D/Documents/ (IOS)
and when i unzip it my zip file deseapear and i do not see the decompressed files in this folder, nothing. However, I have a success alert.

Do you know what is wrong?

Thx

Comment: Is guess the paths are not right and do you know what is in the 'data'? You are only checking if its not 0. prolly there will be an error inside

Comment: data return 0 or -1, is there an error callback with zip plugin ? i don't have any error in my inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it must unzip files in a folder, eg : cdvfile://localhost/persistent/**files**/uploads